# Delete Record on Non Duplicate Key

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to insert, update, and delete all in one MySQL query. I have a DB with about 100 records with a primary key. I'm updating the DB from a CSV file. What I would like to happen is if a record is in the csv and not in the db, then add it. If it's in the db and the csv, update it. If it's in the db and not in the csv, delete it. I have the insert and update part working, but I'm hung up on the delete part.

Here is my query so far:

```
INSERT INTO mydb
(tourID,agent) VALUES (:tourID,:agent) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
tourID=:tourID
```

Is there anything like 'on non duplicate key delete'?

Comment: No. Why not have a 'hidden' flag, and update that instead of deleting the record.

Comment: How would I update that separate than the duplicate key?

Comment: Truncate the table before loading it from the csv file. Assuming that the csv file contains complete records

Comment: How are you determining the records that were deleted from the CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an extra column named "toDelete". At the beginning of your transaction, set it to true for all rows. When you update a row, set it to false. When you are done, delete every row where toDelete is still true.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudocode:

1. For each record in the CSV file, run your `INSERT INTO` query.
2. Run a `DELETE FROM mydb WHERE tourID NOT IN (comma-separated list of tourIDs from CSV)`

How you come up with that `comma-separated list of tourIDs from CSV` depends on how you're processing your CSV file.